# Setting DestDir from Inno Pascal?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to install files in different folders, depending on whether the user has selected to install for all users or just the current user.

I have added used CreateInputOptionPage() to create an option page with two radio buttons.

However, my installer is now littered with lots of duplicate lines, like these two:

```
Source: {#ProjectRootFolder}\License.txt; DestDir: {userdocs}\{#MyAppName}; Check: NOT IsAllUsers
Source: {#ProjectRootFolder}\License.txt; DestDir: {commondocs}\{#MyAppName}; Check:IsAllUsers
```

Is there a more elegant way to do the above? Can Pascal code, for example, create a variable like #define does so I can use it in place of {userdocs} and {commondocs} above?

Further details:

The IsAllUsers() function above calls this code:

```
function IsAllUsers: Boolean;
begin
#ifdef UPDATE
  Result := AllUsersInRegistryIsTRUE;
#else
  Result := AllUsersOrCurrentUserPage.Values[1]; // wizard page second radio button
#endif
end;
```

and:

```
function AllUsersInRegistryIsTRUE: Boolean;  // True if preceding install was to all users' documents 
var
  AllUsersRegValue: AnsiString;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\MyApp', 'AllUsers', AllUsersRegValue) then
    Result := (UpperCase(AllUsersRegValue) = 'YES')
  else
    Result := FALSE;
end;
```

Comment: Sertac has given a good answer, but remember that the user runnign the setup may not be the expected user that is logged in to the computer. In this case, your "only this user" data will end up belonging to an entirely different "this user".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will something like this suit?

```
[Files]
Source: {#ProjectRootFolder}\License.txt; DestDir: {code:GetDir}\{#MyAppName};

...

[Code]
var
  OptionsPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OptionsPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpUserInfo, 
              'please select', 'the kind of installation', 'and continue..', 
              True, False);
  OptionsPage.Add('All users');
  OptionsPage.Values[0] := True;
  OptionsPage.Add('This user');
end;

function GetDir(Dummy: string): string;
begin
  if OptionsPage.Values[0] then
    Result := ExpandConstant('{commondocs}')
  else
    Result := ExpandConstant('{userdocs}');
end;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Sertac.  I wasn't aware of the {code:} syntax. Thanks so much!