# Convert {constants} returned by CurrentFilename in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

What to do to get nice, full filename from the code below:

```
;bugfixes
Source: "Bugfixes\CombatGameConstants.json"; DestDir: "{code:battletechDataDir}\constants";\
    Flags: uninsneveruninstall; Components: DataBugfixes; BeforeInstall: BackupFile()
```

and the `BackupFile()` procedure:

```pascal
procedure BackupFile();
var fileToBackup : String;
begin
  { if backup file already exists skip creation, otherwise rename the file to file.backup }
  fileToBackup := CurrentFilename(); { get destination file name }
  if not FileExists(fileToBackup + '.backup') then
  begin
    if not RenameFile(fileToBackup, fileToBackup + '.backup') then
      MsgBox('Creation backup file for ' + fileToBackup + ' failed!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

This does not convert `{code:battletechDataDir}` into full path – `CurrentFileName()` returns me `{code:battletechDataDir}\constants\{code:battletechDataDir}\constants`. So either how to convert that `{code:battletechDataDir}` into directory, or backup given file other way?

Comment: Where do you set the ```code:battletechDataDir```value? If you would check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940518/setting-destdir-from-inno-pascal/10941714#10941714), you can see that one must provide a method/function when using ```code:``` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```pascal
fileToBackup := ExpandConstant(CurrentFilename()); { get destination file name }
```

---

Though [`CurrentFilename`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_currentfilename) is intended for use with wildcard source. With a fixed file name, you might as well refer to the file explicitly:

```pascal
fileToBackup := battletechDataDir('') + '\constants\CombatGameConstants.json';
```

Comment: Already figured usage of ExpandConstant(CurrentFilename());on my own, but you'll get credit netherless mate.